# What is the difference between "so to do" and "to do so"

Tags: etymology, dialects, infinitives

I believe that both are correct. I.e.

> I have got the Christmas Eve off this year but my partner has failed so to do.

is equivalent to

> I have got the Christmas Eve off this year but my partner has failed to do so.

However, are they equivalent?

Comment: We can explain anything away as a hyperbaton, but that won't make it idiomatic or comprehensible.

Comment: "Has failed so to do" sounds ungrammatical to me (American English speaker).

Comment: failed so to do is extremely old fashioned and would not be used today. So, if you want to sound stilted, use: so to do.

Answer (score 1):

The second clause in each sentence is grammatical, but both are unlikely to occur in normal circumstances, the first particularly so. A native English speaker would say something like ‘. . . but my partner hasn’t.’

In the first clause in each sentence, ‘the Christmas Eve’ is ungrammatical. No article is normally used before the names of holidays and festivals.

Comment: Interesting. Never been called a non-native speaker before must be my Yorkshire accent.

Comment: I donna know, but the 2nd version's *"but my partner has failed to do so"* is fine to my AmE ears, and AmE eyes. Now as to that 1st version's *"but my partner has failed* **so** *to do"*, that sounds like something one of them BrE speakers might be guilty of sayin'. Just sayin'. :)

Comment: This does not address the question at all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a name for each of the forms here, but I don't recall ever being taught this very well, and it's ridiculously hard to know quite what to search for!

I see three possible versions: "to do so", "to so do", and "so to do". They sound progressively more formal (and older) to me.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

*He was told to get off, and he did.  **His brother, on the other hand,*** ...

> ***failed to do so***.

or

> ***failed so to do***.

Either version works for me (UK) and means the same thing, although the second sounds more dialect/formal/correct.  Somewhere in the back of my mind is an old saw (Churchill I think) about prepositions at the end of sentences being something "...up with which I will not put".

Answer (score -1):

I think, it's a fronting concept.
To do so is written as so to do.

I made upma, but my brother failed to do so.
I made upma, but my brother failed so to do.

- To do so., = to make upma.,
  I made upma, but my brother failed to make upma. So, the so here is a pronoun, I think.
- So to do., = upma to make.,  ( object is fronted)
  I made upma, but my brother failed upma to make ( = to make upma)

I don't know exactly. I'm also looking for proper explanation.,
So is used for previous verb likewise., I have read.

Or

- to do so = to do likewise.,
  I made upma, but my brother failed to make likewise.
- so to do = likewise to do.,
  I made upma, but my brother failed likewise to make.

Comment: What is 'upma'?